# how to create an segmented arrow line on SVG.JS

Tags: svg, svg.js

How can i create a segmented line dynamically using svg.js who can be redirected among objects, on the same  container

[Example arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ONIl.png)

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Howdy, welcome to SO. Generally you'll want to show a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing progress towards your issue you've made on your own. This helps the site remain a Q/A site as opposed to a tutorial/free code service type site. However, I can say you don't need svg.js to accomplish this. You don't even need SVG, you could accomplish this with pure CSS if you wanted. :)

Comment: Use `stroke-dasharray` for the line and add a `<marker>` for the arrow point. If you need more help please add your code.

Comment: i prefer not use css, only svg, and i have a already made svg on inkscape, i like to add the arrow dynamically, prefer using svg.js as i use in another functions

Comment: [For the arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker), and [for the dashed line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray).

Comment: many thanks it worked

Answer (score 0):

```html
<svg width="600px" height="100px">
<defs>
     <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refX="0" refY="3" orient="auto" markerUnits="strokeWidth">
       <path d="M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z" fill="#000"></path>
     </marker>
</defs>

<line id="line1" x1="50" y1="30" x2="250" y2="30" stroke-dasharray="16" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" marker-end="url(#arrow)"></line>
</svg>
```